# How do I turn off large titles for UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableView and a Detail View embedded in a UINavigationController as so: [image]I would like to turn on large titles for "My Notes" but I'd like to turn it off for the detail view. Something like how the default Mail app works on iPhone. How would I change the navigation bar's `prefersLargeTitle` property during that segue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

it's very simple.

In your **DetailView** you should set **navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode** to **.never**

(not *navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode* !!)

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

Answer (score 21):

### SwiftUI version

```
.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
```

Update for iOS 14 and later:

```
.navigationTitle("Details")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

Comment: For future iOS releases, this method will be removed. The following method should be used instead: `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`. Plus the navigation title could be set with `.navigationTitle("Details")`

Answer (score 6):

Any one of both of following, will solve your problem:

1. set prefersLargeTitles to **false** for your navigationBar

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
   ```
2. set largeTitleDisplayMode to **never** for navigationItem (note: prefersLargeTitles must be **false** otherwise this won't work)

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
   ```

**Note**: if `prefersLargeTitles` is true, then largeTitleDisplayMode = .never won't work. Small title display for navigation bar is dependent on `prefersLargeTitles`

This will enable large title mode if it's value is **true**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Comment: This is just incorrect. prefersLargeTitles doesn't have to be false for #2. And largeTitleDisplayMode = .never will definitely work when prefersLargeTitles is true.

Comment: It is also important to note that this is only available in iOS 11+.

Comment: Just wanted to note that in my case #1 and #2 both needed (just #2 was not enough), even when prefer large title flag was set to "Never" in navigationItem's settings in storyboard.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue just now.

My use case:

**MasterVC:** basic navigation bar without largeTitle

**DetailVC:** largeTitle enabled

--> When going back to the MasterVC from the DetailVC I was seeing a weird animation which showed a largeTitle on the Master for a sec before going back to the basic non largeTitle layout. It looked like a glitch.

I fixed it by following this approach:

**In MasterVC** - **viewDidLoad**

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
     navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

**In DetailVC** - **viewDidLoad**

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
     navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

I hope that can help others.

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that if you set `largeTitleDisplayMode` to never, and `prefersLargeTitles` to false on a detail `ViewController`, the small title will continue to display for a second when moving from the detail `ViewController` to the previous `ViewController` via the `UINavigationBar` back button.

Use `willMove(toParent:)` function to change the title back before the segue is performed.

### Swift 4

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItem.LargeTitleDisplayMode.never
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Comment: You should provide more context around your answer. Where is this code going? What is it doing?

Comment: @NicolasGrenié, the code is pretty clear because properties in iOS are self-descriptive. Your comment, in turn seems to be left in hurry or even generated by a bot.

Comment: `UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever` also works, since the implication here is that you don't have access to `.never`. @NicolasGrenié You might want to consider some basic tutorials before worrying about title bar size.

Answer (score 4):

It might be very late but this could be useful for someone..

include the below code on your detail view controller under viewDidLoad

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

Answer (score 2):

**SwiftUI:**

step 1. Use ZStack
step 2 : .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and needed to place a NavigationItem on the second ViewController's storyboard. My NavigationItem was being created automatically by the segue and its `prefersLargeTitle` in the `viewDidLoad()` was not finished loading before the view appeared. Adding a NavigationItem to the storyboard fixed this issue and allowed me to set the `prefersLargeTitle` in the storyboard's properties menu.