# Large UINavigationBar resize smoothly when popping back too rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

hey guys I've used large UINavigationBar in a child ViewController and i want to resize my navBar to default size when popping back to rootViewController smoothly.

vc's gif:https://giphy.com/gifs/1P0HwqlIqqMnzibxbH

**EDIT**

I don't want to remove largeNavBar from parent vc, i only want to disappear it gradually and with animation like app store:https://giphy.com/gifs/YXsTA6I5r0lGik1gC8

here is the child vc code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.initUI()
    super.enableLargeNavigationTitle(title: (self.favorty?.sellerProduct?.product?.name)!)

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    super.removeTitleImage()

}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(true)        

}
```

here  is the enableLargeNavigationBar function:

```
func enableLargeNavigationTitle(title: String)  {

    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = VVUtility.splashBackGroundColor()
    self.navigationItem.title = "\(title)".localized()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font : VVUtility.normalFontWithPlusSize(increaseSize: -2.0)]

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = VVUtility.splashBackGroundColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font : VVUtility.normalFontWithPlusSize(increaseSize: 0.0)]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}
```

disableLargeNavigation function:

```
func disableLargeNavigationTitle() {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

here is parent vc code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.initUI()
    self.getData()
    super.disableLargeNavigationTitle()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBarBoxView)
    self.timerDelegate?.startTimer()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.searchBarBoxView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.timerDelegate?.stopTimer()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    super.disableLargeNavigationTitle()

}
```

Comment: why you undo my edit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn off large titles for UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908031/how-do-i-turn-off-large-titles-for-uinavigationbar)

Comment: @LalKrishna i'm new to stackoverflow i would be thankful if you do that again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Try putting this code in `awakeFromNib()` for each view controller, with the settings changed as you need.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    // Large titles
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false // This could be true for other view controller
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never // This could be .always for other view controller
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black] // Or whatever you want
    } else {
        // Handle iOS 10 and below (no large titles)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I think you can do this just in Storyboard, but that didn’t work for me.